# c# decimal number in textbox preventing printing datagridview

Tags: c#, printing, type-conversion

Hi Guys so i have paidtextbox and pricetext box that calculate the change in changetxt box but everytime i try to print a paid amount of 3.75 it throws the error input string was not in a correct format this is the code. i tried changeing convert.todecimal but it throws a error and does not apply the a-b

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(paidtextbox.Text);
    int b = Convert.ToInt32(pricetxtbox.Text);
    int c = a - b;
    changetxtbox.Text = Convert.ToString(c);

    //printing
    printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
    printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typing problem. An Integer cannot store a decimal value. You should be using decimal as the type for a,b, and c. There is a matching Convert.ToDecimal() method, but you may want to look into the usage pattern for decimal.TryParse(). It will allow you to also do error handling on invalid text box data.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx